# Traduction de « Feedback »

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot

J'étais en train d'écrire un [« post » sur le meta de ce site](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/421/new-french-career-stack-overflow) et j'ai complètement bloqué sur la traduction du mot « feedback » ou de l'expression « asking for feedback » lors de la traduction de l'anglais au français.

J'ai finalement opté pour

> demande notre avis sur […]

Mais je ne suis pas sûr si c'est vraiment l'expression appropriée.

[Google propose](http://translate.google.com/#en/fr/feedback) les choix suivants :

- réaction
- information de retour
- effet larsen *(ceci correspond au « feedback » électrique)*
- retour d'information

**Qu'en pensez vous?**

*Je ne parle pas du « feedback » au sens électrique du terme!*

---

Voici deux phrases qui pourraient servir d'exemple à traduire

> - They are asking for feedback
> - Feedback wanted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C'est vrai que feedback n'est pas toujours facile à traduire et les gens vont même jusqu'à utiliser le mot anglais.

Quand une personne attend un retour de notre part, elle souhaite en fin de compte connaître notre avis sur le sujet. Du coup, je préfère la traduction suivante :

> *Feedback wanted*
>   Votre/Ton avis nous intéresse

Pour la première phrase, tout dépend du contexte. En entreprise ou dans le monde du travail, si on est amené à expérimenter quelque chose (une machine, un logiciel, un service), effectivement la traduction serait :

> *They are asking for feedback*
>   Ils demandent un retour d'expérience

Après, pour la tournure, tout dépend du contexte (phrase seule, dans un paragraphe ?). Ce pourrait être aussi traduit par :

> Un retour d'expérience est demandé

Pour le mot **réaction**, c'est plus feedback dans le sens **réponse à une situation**. À la fin d'un article sur le web, on peut lire de temps à autre : **réagir à cet article** dans le sens **qu'en pensez-vous ?**. Ça peut être aussi **commentez cet article** mais on s'éloigne du feedback au niveau de la traduction.

Après un match, un concert, un film, on pourrait demander au spectateur son **impression** de cette manière :

> Quelle est votre/ton impression ?
>   Quelle est votre/ta première impression ? *(si c'est un avis à chaud)*

Enfin, les traductions *information de retour*, *retour d'information* et *effet larsen* (dans ce cas) ne sont pas correctes.

Answer (score 9):

Pour les exemples

> *They are asking for feedback*
>   Ils demandent des retours/rapport d'expérience

ou

> Ils demandent des commentaires

Et

> *Feedback wanted*
>   Appel à commentaires

Dans le cas général j'ai souvent entendu *feedback* en anglais dans le texte, souvent de la part d'un public *knowledgeable* en informatique/électronique et/ou branchouille (ça fait jeune cadre dynamique ou vieux technicien, quoi¹). Sinon je parlerais de *critique*, d'*avis* ou de *commentaires* pour une traduction directe ou je contournerais la difficulté avec des tournures du type « donnez-nous vos impressions ».

---

<sub>¹ Ou jeune technicien dynamique ou vieux cadre ou…</sub>

Comment: For what it's worth at this late date, +1 for "commentaires."

Answer (score 6):

Quand j'écris un rapport, une note ou un compte-rendu, je l'envoie à quelques relecteurs pour leur demander s'ils ont des remarques ou des commentaires sur ma production. Quelque chose comme:

> Vos remarques sont les bienvenues.

Comment: For what it's worth at this late date, +1 for mentioning "commentaires."

Answer (score 5):

Feedback wanted or I am waiting for your feedback:

> J'attends un retour

In French you can say “*un retour*” which means “some feedback”.

Answer (score 2):

Personnellement, je dirais « retour d'expérience ».

Answer (score 0):

Dans le monde universitaire on emploie souvent *feedback*. Une autre solution est tout simplement retour. Je n'ai guère entendu toute l'expression retour d'information ou retour d'expérience. Selon linguee dépendant du contexte on peut aussi le traduire par commentaire(s), réaction(s), échos, etc. Il y a aussi une question plus recente pertinente [Utilisation du mot «feedback» en français](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25079/utilisation-du-mot-feedback-en-fran%C3%A7ais).

Answer (score -3):

En communication " feedback " est une déformation  de la première information reçue

Comment: La question porte sur la communication entre humains, pas sur la théorie de l'information. Le sens de “déformation” est très particulier à la théorie de l'information, le terme n'a pas du tout ce sens ou cette connotation en général.