# Utilisation du mot «feedback» en français

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, usage, anglicismes

J'ai bien vu cette [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6370/traduction-de-feedback) sur la traduction du mot *feedback* en français, mais j'ai aussi vu cet article de [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/feedback), qui montre qu'au moins un sens technique du mot *feedback* est reconnu depuis les années soixante en France.

Est-ce que les expressions *donner du feedback* et *demander du feedback* sont utilisées en France dans un contexte professionnel, ou bien le mot *feedback* est-il encore restreint au sens technique de l'article de CNRTL?

D'après [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=donner%20du%20feedback&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdonner%20du%20feedback%3B%2Cc0), *donner du feedback* a fait un bond depuis 1994, mais *demander du feedback* est inconnu. Mais ngrams utilise un certain corpus, écrit, qui ne correspond pas forcément à ce que l'on dit en conversation. Et même si ngrams montre une progression très rapide, il est difficile de se faire une idée de l'étendue réelle de l'utilisation du mot.

NOTE: ceci n'est pas une question de traduction, et n'est donc pas similaire à la question précédente mentionnée ci-dessus. C'est une question sur l'usage d'un mot anglais en France. Je souhaite mieux comprendre la pénétration de ce mot en France aujourd'hui, à l'aide d'un ... *feedback* (!) direct.

Comment: This anecdote is Canadian, but you reminded me of quelque chose qui s'est passée à la radio il y a quelques mois. It was on the small-league [CHOQ-FM](http://choqfm.ca) Toronto station for francophones. The interviewee and interviewer had joked about the importance of speaking in French, and then a few sentences later the interviewee unthinkingly used the word "feedback"... The two hesitated for a second, I suppose gênés by the realization that they didn't have a French substitute ready to hand. Finally the interviewer haltingly suggested: "Ce que... ce que disent les gens." :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak - je serais aussi intéressé par le point de vue Québecois sur la question. J'assume que _feedback_ n'est pas acceptable au Québec, mais je me trompe peut-être?

Comment: Le grand dictionnaire terminologique omits it. The official OQLF answer is "[don't use it](http://ow.ly/53xL309Pr9r)": "On évitera l'emprunt intégral *feedback*, car ce terme ne comble aucune lacune lexicale, le terme français *rétroaction* étant tout à fait adéquat." (They call ["integral" borrowings](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3787) those that are not adapted to French morphology or phonology.) But [another page](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=502394) notes less dogmatically: "L'emprunt **feedback** est souvent utilisé en français."

Comment: I haven't spent enough time in Québec (rather than Ontario), but I suspect that the picture is similar there: people would often say "feedback" in regular conversation despite the official injunction. Not very many of the official replacement terms manage to oust English emprunts, in my experience. If I knew where to find good Québec-specific data I'd put together an actual answer...

Comment: [Another entry](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8364502) for the technical sense reads: "Le terme français *rétroaction*, qui traduit très bien le terme anglais *feedback*, est très répandu et permet d'éviter l'usage de cet emprunt intégral." Assuming that's not disingenuous, perhaps it has caught on better than the radio hosts' usage would suggest. Also, searching "feedback" on the English side reveals a few more senses, including "réaction" for the non-technical sense and a few more variations for the [AV sense](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8411861).

Comment: Here it is in [a 1990 scientific article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1495110?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)...

Comment: In a work context, _ask for feedback_ and _give feedback_ are commonplace in the US, but I'm wondering if a similar usage exists in France. _Rétroaction_ would not work for that context. Of course, French companies might very well not care about _giving feedback_ to their employees ;-)

Comment: Heh. :p I expect that they would recommend [*réaction*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8363358) for that purpose... but that actual companies might use [*feedback*](http://www.portailrh.org/votre_emploi/fiche_lapresse.aspx?f=25689).

Comment: Vraiment? Mais ce n'est pas vraiment une _réaction_ - qui semble être quelque chose de court et pas forcément construit comme un _feedback_ professionnel?

Comment: It's more "a French term at any cost" than "the most suitable term" with them, I think... but perhaps "commentaires" is more suitable if you allow that tiny bit of grammatical transposition. (Sadly, not mentioned in those equivalence articles in the GDT.) That said, linguee.fr gives these two equivalent sentences from a Québec government site: "Is there adequate feedback to applicants on their proposals?" = "Fournit-on aux candidats une rétroaction adéquate sur leurs propositions?", which is at least a related meaning... :)

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu dire *donner **du** feedback* ou *demander **du** feedback* (indénombrable). J'ai toujours entendu feedback construit comme *avis*, et donc *demander un/son/leurs feedback(s)* *donner son feedback*, *un feedback positif ou négatif*.

Comment: @jlliagre Never seems too strong. "Il nous ont pas donné de feedback" sounds perfectly normal to my ears

Comment: @Eauquidort And sounds normal spoken French to mines too. *Pas de* works for both countable and uncountable. *J'ai un avis*, *je n'ai pas d'avis*, *donne-moi ton avis* but **never** *donne-moi de l'avis* .

Comment: @jlliagre - _donner un feedback_ est très _années 80_ d'après ngrams, et cette expression semble maintenant en perte de vitesse par rapport à _donner du feedback_ ;-)

Comment: Frank, non ! NGram place même *donner un feedback* légèrement au dessus de *donner du feedback* pour la dernière valeur rapportée (1.27 vs 1.04 pour cent millions en 2008 avec le *smoothing* par défaut). Pour le XXIe siècle, il ne trouve que treize livres contenant *donner du feedback* et six *donner un feedback*, ce qui est de toute façon un peu léger pour être significatif. Maintenant que je l'ai lu, ça ne me choque pas outre-mesure comme l'aurait fait *donner de l'avis* mais je confirme que je n'ai tout de même jamais entendu dire *donner du feedback*.

Comment: Ah oui! C'est vrai! J'avais pris les paramètres par défaut qui s'arrêtaient en 2000 - je viens maintenant d'essayer jusqu'en 2017, et je vois la valeur pour 2008. C'est bien _donner un feedback_ qui est en tête en ce moment, mais _donner du feedback_ n'est pas inconnu, et a même été "populaire" (si l'on peut dire...) en 2008. Comme je le disais de toute façon, ngrams se base sur certains livres (sont-ils même "représentatifs"? (à définir)), donc j'aimerais surtout savoir ce que vous entendez, ce qui se dit vraiment en France ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre - ok - j'avais voulu distinguer d'avec le Québec, mais vous avez raison. Je vais simplifier. Mais veuillez noter que j'avais réussi (un peu comme Monsieur Jourdain) à utiliser du premier coup la forme _correcte_ _un feedback_ ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En entreprise, le mot « feedback » est très utilisé. Surtout par les commerciaux, qui parlent anglais avec une partie de leur clients.

Exemples:

> On a envoyé la dernière version au client, on attend son feedback pour avancer.
>
> On a demandé un feedback à toute les équipes, on lance la production si elles ont toutes validé.

*Feedback* ne représente pas ici un document mais simplement l'opinion retournée par une personne ou un groupe de personnes face à une nouveauté ou un changement.

Cette opinion peut être simplement un avis positif, neutre ou négatif, ou être plus précise et circonstanciée mais un *feedback* n'est pas ici un rapport de 250 pages contenant une analyse détaillée des qualités et défauts de ce dont il est question.

Cette opinion ne s'applique pas en général à une personne, mais plutôt à un produit, projet, mise à jour ou proposition (de contrat).

De manière générale en entreprise on utilise souvent des mots anglais pour des concepts qui sont très connus dans les milieux anglophones mais qui ont pas forcément de bonne traduction. Ex: "Milestone, review, ..."

Comment: Pour renforcer cette réponse, pouvez-vous donner des exemples d'utilisation du mot _feedback_? J'aimerais savoir dans quelles expressions le mot est utilisé.

Comment: @Frank "On a envoyé la dernière version au client, on attend son feedback pour avancer" // "On a demandé un feedback à toute les équipes, on lance la production si elle ont toutes validé"

Comment: +1 C'est exactement ça. Le mot feedback est utilisé dans mon entourage aussi pour désigner l'opinion positive, neutre ou négative retournée par une personne ou un groupe de personnes face à une nouveauté ou un changement.

Comment: Questions supplémentaires: est-ce que vous faites des évaluations annuelles de performance individuelle? Utilisez-vous le mot _feedback_ dans ce contexte? Est-ce que les chefs demandent un _feedback_ de leurs employés? Est-ce que les employés reçoivent un _feedback_ de leur chef?

Comment: Oui, mais sans objet car ma *review* se fait en anglais ;-)

Comment: Hmmm - le _feedback_ se résume-t-il donc plus ou moins a _oui, peu importe, non_, ou peut-il être plus détaillé, comme par exemple, un document de plusieurs pages qui aborderait différents points que le client/les équipes souhaiteraient voir adressés/résolus avant de pouvoir avancer?

Comment: @jlliagre - oui, évidemment ;-) Intéressant - dans l'informatique donc, on n'hésite pas à utiliser l'anglais au bureau?

Comment: @Frank Oui / Non, je pense pas / Oui, c'est possible / C'est plus rare, mais ça doit pouvoir arriver. C'est surtout par rapport à une idée, une version, un planning, etc. Ça peut être dans n'importe quel contexte.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat - vous voulez dire que les employés ne reçoivent pas un _feedback_ de leur chef? Peut-être est-on simplement viré (un feedback négatif) ou gardé (un feedback _suffisant_ ("si on vous garde, ce que vous n'êtes pas trop mauvais, après tout") :-)

Comment: @Frank Non, c'est surtout qu'on reçoit un feedback *de* quelque chose, un produit, une mise à jour etc., et je peux me tromper (c'est sûrement pas vrai partout) mais c'est pas le chef qui va regarder en détail quelque chose pour donner son avis. Je vois ça plus danse les relations inter-services ou avec les clients. Après comme j'ai dit, il y a sûrement des situations ou ça arrive. Sinon pour répondre à une autre de tes questions, on utilise beaucoup plus facilement l'anglais en informatique, pour plusieurs raisons.

Comment: Je vois. _Feedback_ aux US est donc plus large apparemment. Et pour ma question sur l'étendue du feedback? Ici, c'est souvent assez détaillé (document ou pas), pas un simple résultat de sondage.

Comment: En informatique, on n'utilise jamais l'anglais au bureau sauf si on y est obligé, c'est à dire quand il y a avec nous quelqu'un qui ne parle pas le français. C'est le cas de mon chef. En revanche, on utilise parfois du vocabulaire anglais, souvent du jargon technique pour les techniciens/ingénieurs et du jargon financier pour les commerciaux et managers, dont le faux ami "revenue". Feedback n'est pas un document mais une opinion ici.

Comment: Intéressant. Dans d'autres contextes européens (Berlin), il y a des startups en info où *toute* la communication interne est obligatoirement en anglais, et en anglais uniquement, en général pour cause d'intégration d'employés d'origines diverses.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat - si tu mets les exemples dans ta réponse, je la choisis comme réponse à la question. Je peux aussi le faire moi-même, et tu peux éditer si ça ne va pas.

Comment: La loi Toubon impose que toute communication interne soit faite en français. http://www.lexpress.fr/emploi/la-loi-toubon-rempart-contre-le-tout-anglais-au-travail_1250705.html https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_Toubon

Comment: @TeleportingGoat - je ne veux pas être enquiquinant, mais peux-tu aussi ajouter des détails sur le _scope_ d'un _feedback_ à ta réponse. J'ai l'impression qu'il s'agit plutôt en France d'une opinion rapide, presque un "résultat de sondage", alors qu'aux US, ça pourrait être un rapport de 250 pages sur les déficiences du produit d'après le client ...

Comment: Édite si il y a de quoi faire dans les commentaires, sinon je devrai le faire plus tard.

Comment: Je ne suis pas trop à l'aise pour ce qui est du _scope_ exact du mot. Je préférerais que ça vienne de toi ou jlliagre avec votre vécu sur place :-)

Comment: @jlliagre - merci des précisions dans la réponse!

Comment: On peut aussi donner son feedback sur une personne, un nouvel embauché, un nouveau client, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Les anglicismes ne sont pas forcément mauvais, mais il faut observer qu'il existe des mots français tout à fait adaptés:

- Au sens technique (uniquement): [rétroaction](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/r%C3%A9troaction)
- Quand on s'adresse à une personne: "demander un avis", "donner un avis"
- Quand on s'adresse à plusieurs personnes: "**avis**", "**échos**" ou "**retours**" (Voir [Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?il=FR&tool=opensearch&query=feedback) à ce sujet):

> Il a reçu des avis/échos/retours très positifs.

On peut généralement voir une nuance entre les trois:

1. "**avis**" sous-entend que les personnes consultées sont compétentes ou bien placées pour répondre,
2. "**écho**" implique que l'information est reçue sous forme informelle,
3. "**retour**" sous-entend une procédure plus formelle (par exemple sous forme de questionnaires).

Pour les exemples déjà cités:

> Nous souhaitons avoir l'**avis** des clients.
>
> Pourrais-je vous demander votre **avis**?
>
> Nous avons envoyé la dernière version au client, nous attendons son **avis** pour avancer.
>
> Nous avons demandé un **retour** à toutes les équipes, nous lançons la production si elles ont toutes validé.

Answer (score 2):

Dans certains contextes, il s'agit plutôt de simples *nouvelles*. Aucun *feedback* du client : on n'a pas eu de ses nouvelles, on n'en a pas eu [d'échos](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/feedback/580306) etc. On peut par ailleurs attendre l'approbation, l'acceptation, ou simplement la réponse du client etc. pour aller de l'avant. Une personne peut faire l'objet d'une évaluation plus ou moins systématique, elle peut recevoir un mot d'encouragement etc. Au Québec je comprendrais dans un contexte courant donner *du feedback* comme *donner des nouvelles* de manière générique alors que donner *son feedback* serait l'avis ou les commentaires sur un sujet plus précis comme mentionné dans la [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/25081) ; j'ai souvent *entendu* le premier au Québec autant en entreprise qu'ailleurs.

---

À mon avis il y a lieu d'ajouter quelques précisons sur le *feedback* en gestion, et sa traduction (rétroaction) qu'on trouve parfois surprenante. C'est qu'ils n'ont rien à voir avec ce qui précède ni avec l'idée usuelle de donner son avis, ses impressions, de répondre quand on sollicite notre opinion, de fournir des commentaires ou un retour, de réagir etc., tel qu'on l'a correctement traduit dans la question liée. Il s'agit plutôt de verbiage de *management/fintech* :

> Information tirée d'une situation et utilisée pour le contrôle,
>   l'évaluation ou la correction immédiate ou future de cette situation,
>   **par exemple le fait de dire aux membres du personnel de quelle façon
>   leur rendement se compare avec ce qui était attendu d'eux dans
>   l'espoir que cette information les incitera à améliorer leur
>   comportement et à réduire les coûts de main-d'œuvre non productifs**.
>
> [ GDT d'une [définition](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=502394) de *rétroaction/feedback* de l'*Institut
>   Canadien des Comptables Agréés*, 2006 provenant du *Dictionnaire de la
>   comptabilité et de la gestion financière*, je souligne ]

Ce n'est pas une manière compliquée de dire donner son opinion que ça, mais plutôt l'idée de communiquer des indicateurs de performance, ou de la validation d'un processus par retour d'information continuelle à la personne qui l'administre. C'est une extension du sens technique de « dispositif d'auto-correction ». C'est dans ce cadre que s'insère aussi la [*retro-information*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2096666).

Comment: Tiens, d'ailleurs le mot du jour, c'est _rétro-propagation_. Voilà un mot parfaitement en pointe :-)

Answer (score 1):

En France on dit plutôt "**donner un feedback**" que "donner *du* feedback". Néanmoins, ce terme n'est pas compris par tous les français.

Answer (score 0):

Dans le monde universitaire, le monde industriel et celui des entreprises, on utilise souvent le mot *feedback*. C'est comme avec le mot *reviewer* ; bien qu'il existe des mots français homologues, on préfère l'anglicisme:-)! Je pense que les étudiants en Master l'utilisent plus que les étudiants en Licence. Il y a aussi une question recente pertinente

[Contexte et orthographe du mot « feedback »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/37395/contexte-et-orthographe-du-mot-feedback)

Comment: Pourquoi "bien sûr" ? Qu'est-ce qui incite les étudiants en master à plus utiliser *feedback* que ceux de licence ?

Comment: @jlliagre Les étudiants en master sont plus à l'aise avec l'anglais ; voire ils le maîtrisent suffisamment ; on peut leuer demander par exemple de lire des articles scientifiques en anglais. Parfois avec les étudiants en licence l'emploi des mots anglicismes c'est un peu de taboo:-)! Mais mon expérience proviennent des petites universités. Peut-être dans des universités de plus grande taille et réputation la situation est différente.

Comment: @jlliagre je viens de modifier l'affirmation:-)!

Comment: Aïe ! On ne peut pas demander à des étudiants en licence de lire un article en anglais... Le niveau baisse... J'espère que ça ne concerne pas aussi les étudiants en licence d'anglais ;-)

Comment: "reviewer", jamais entendu.  Par curiosité, ça se prononce comment ?  /rəvjuve/ ou /rəvjue/ ?