# Contexte et orthographe du mot « feedback »

Tags: traduction, anglais, anglicismes, registre

Il me semble que le mot « feedback » est assez répandu dans le monde académique, le monde industriel, et celui des entreprises et du commerce.
Peut-on l'utiliser en dehors de ces contextes ?
Le mot « rétroaction » est-il aussi courant ?
Quelle orthographe doit-on employer ? Feedback, feed-back, feed back ?

Comment: "rétroactif" signifie une chose (notamment une loi) ayant un effet (une action) sur le passé.

Comment: en français on va utiliser retour : "Je voudrais ton retour sur cette idée"

Comment: @BaptisteGavalda Feedback n'est pas considéré comme français ?

Comment: @Dimitris Feedback est évidemment un anglicisme mais son usage est largement répandu dans les domaines que vous avez cité.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

« Rétroaction » n'est jamais employé pour désigner feedback dans le sens du retour d'expérience. Il est employé dans d'autres domaines, notamment juridique, mais pas dans le sens très répandu du feedback que, par exemple, les entreprises aiment recevoir.

#### [feedback](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/feedback) \fid.bak\ masculin (orthographe rectifiée de 1990) (Anglicisme)

1. Retour d’expérience, d’information.
   La palette est très large. Mais pour chacun d’entre vous, tout doit être clair. Nous voulons donc tout simplifier. Et c’est pour cela que vos feedbacks sont hyper précieux. — (Octave Klaba, OVH Summit 2018, 18 octobre 2018)
2. (Automatique) Rétroaction, boucle de rétroaction.
3. (Ingénierie du son) Retour du son, boucle, Larsen.

L'orthographe fut rectifiée depuis *feed-back* en 1990.

Comme signalé par @BaptisteGavalda, feedback sera parfois traduit par « retour », faisant écho au retour d'expérience.

> Quel est ton retour sur cette réunion ?

Comment: Merci. Synonymes : Retour d’expérience, rétroaction (selon le lien)

Comment: @Dimitris Oui, le lien indique que rétroaction est un synonyme, ce qui n'est pas juste pour le retour d'expérience, et en cliquant sur rétroaction on s'apperçoit qu'il ne l'est pas. Dans d'autres contextes, juridiques notamment, rétroaction est synonyme. Je n'ai jamais entendu ni lu ce mot pour le domaine du retour d'expérience ou d'information en entreprise. Probablement aussi en partie car c'est beaucoup moins « vendeur » que feedback.

Answer (score 2):

L'orthographe reconnue par le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/feedback) est « feed back » ou « feed-back », cependant un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feedback%2Cfeed-back%2Cfeed+back&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfeedback%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfeed%20-%20back%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfeed%20back%3B%2Cc0) montre que « feedback » est devenu récemment l'orthographe préférée.

La même référence du TLFi citée ci-dessus montre que le mot est véritablement un synonyme du mot « rétroaction » et qu'il est applicable dans le domaine de l'automation et en neurologie.

La référence suivante devrait répondre amplement à la question sur l'équivalence des termes aussi bien qu'à celle sur l'étendue du domaine de son application : [ref](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9troaction).

Pour ce qui est de l'utilisation en dehors du monde global de la science on peut se référer à la [question suivante](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6370/17649), qui semble montrer que l'on ne traduit pas l'anglais « feedback » dans ce domaine-là par « feedback », ce qui signifie que l'on ne l'emploie pas et que l'on a recours à des mots d'origine française.